# How to Set Height of PdfPTable in iTextSharp in c#

Tags: c#, itext

How to Set Height of PdfPTable in iTextSharp

I downloaded the last version of iTextSharp dll.

I generate an PdfPTable object and I have to set it's cell height.

I have tried with:

```
table = new PdfPTable(colCount);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
table.WidthPercentage = 100;
table.TotalHeight = 20000f;
```

But without success because the exception is :

`Can not assign a value to the property or to the indexer 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable.TotalHeight' because it is read-only`.

How can i do it?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set the cell height. The `TotalHeight` property is read-only. Usually, the height of the table is determined by the content you're adding to the table.

If you really want to fix the height of a table, you need to set the `FixedHeight` property of each `PdfPCell`. However: if you set the fixed height of a cell and you add content that doesn't fit in that cell, all the content that doesn't fit will be omitted.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply, now I understand. But not exists one method in `iTextSharp` for automatic set width and height with respect to length of the numeric or text content in the cell?

Comment: No, that's not how PDF works: PDF needs fixed measurements. One way to work around this, is by converting HTML snippets to PDF, but that's a completely different question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help !